# Extract fields from a json substring - logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm fairly new to `Logstash` filtering stuff. I've below json string

```
{
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Foo Facts: oma_phase: prd, oma_app: fsd, oma_apptype: obe, oma_componenttype: oltp, oma_componentname: -, oma_peak: pk99, oma_phaselevel: prd"
}
```

I would like to extract the fields `oma_phase, oma_app, oma_apptype, oma_componenttype, oma_componentname, oma_peak & oma_phaselevel`.

I've tried below native json filter,

```
filter {
  if [type] == "ansible" {
    json {
      source => "ansible_result"
    }
  }
}
```

Here `ansible_result` is the key holding the above json value. However, there are many keys having different values but with the same `ansible_result` key. This is creating lot of index keys and I don't want that.

I would like to have some sort of filter which can match the substring `Foo Facts` and there after extracting the `oma_*` fields.

I somehow couldn't managed to do with `grok` filter to match the substring. It would be really great if you could help me with this.

Many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
filter {
    json {
    source => "message"
    }
   }
```

the ansible_result json will be considered as a message.

Comment: I tried this. `message` isn't the same json as `ansible_result`. In fact, `message` isn't the json at all. I got parsing errors.

Answer (score 0):

It was little difficult in the beginning but eventually managed to crack the grok.

`\"msg\": \"Foo Facts: oma_phase: %{DATA:oma_phase}, oma_app: %{DATA:oma_app}, oma_apptype: %{DATA:oma_apptype},( oma_componenttype: %{DATA:oma_componenenttype},)? oma_componentname: %{DATA:oma_componenentname}, oma_peak: %{DATA:oma_peak}, oma_phaselevel: %{DATA:oma_phaselevel}\"`

From the logs, I got to know `oma_componenttype` is missing for some logs. So I marked it as an optional field with `()?`

It wouldn't have been possible without the help of below online parsers.

1. [grokdebug](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)
2. [Grok Constructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result)